# After fresh install, Ubuntu 16.04.2 restarts spontaneously at random times

Tags: 16.04, reboot

I am an Ubuntu user for about 5 years although I am short on technical knowledge when it comes to errors and problems on ubuntu. Throughout these years, I was using dual boot of Windows and Ubuntu. Since I was facing some problems with Windows and Ubuntu (I was not able to install any softwares or update Ubuntu), I decided to reinstall ubuntu after erasing all existing operating systems i.e. Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10. However, after the fresh installation, I am facing troubles with spontaneous random restarts. I use Acer laptop which I bought 5 months ago and so far I have not faced any such problem in this new laptop or with the older Acer laptop. The details of the problems are as follows:

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 using bootable USB drive. The updates were done after the installation. After the update was completed, I started installing softwares from software center. The first random restart was observed immediately after installation of VLC media player. The monitor just went off and suddenly the opening page for password came up. After this, the laptop restarted several times while I was performing other activities like using LibreOffice, using software center, browsing etc. Sometimes, the laptop restarted three or four times within 5 minutes time. Before I completed writing draft of this post in LibreOffice, the laptop restarted five times.  I noticed that this problem did not  occur when the laptop was standby or when I was watching videos for hours.

I tried to do some solutions I found online. But so far no result. I have very little knowledge with command-line operations and most of the times, I find it difficult to understand the technical languages as well. It would be a great help if anyone could help me with this problem. I have some deadlien coming up and I am worried if I would be able to finish that work as this problem continues.

I found a crash 06:57. But I don't know how to interpret it and solve it. I also tried to remove unattended upgrades using command line.

```
$ last |head -n 100
anita    tty7         :0               Mon May 22 09:52    gone - no logout
anita    tty7         :0               Mon May 22 09:52 - 09:52  (00:00)
anita    tty7         :0               Mon May 22 09:45 - 09:52  (00:06)
anita    tty7         :0               Mon May 22 09:27 - 09:45  (00:18)
anita    tty7         :0               Mon May 22 09:18 - 09:27  (00:08)
anita    tty7         :0               Mon May 22 09:13 - 09:18  (00:05)
anita    tty7         :0               Mon May 22 09:06 - 09:13  (00:07)
anita    tty7         :0               Mon May 22 06:58 - 09:06  (02:08)
anita    tty7         :0               Mon May 22 06:56 - 06:58  (00:01)
anita    tty7         :0               Mon May 22 06:52 - 06:56  (00:03)
anita    tty7         :0               Mon May 22 06:27 - 06:52  (00:25)
anita    tty7         :0               Mon May 22 05:45 - 06:27  (00:41)
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-52-generic Mon May 22 05:45   still running
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 22:40 - down   (00:01)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 15:24 - 22:40  (07:16)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 15:21 - 15:23  (00:02)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 15:18 - 15:21  (00:02)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 13:37 - 15:18  (01:41)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 13:32 - 13:37  (00:04)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 12:54 - 13:32  (00:37)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 11:08 - 12:54  (01:45)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 11:05 - 11:08  (00:02)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 10:53 - 11:05  (00:12)
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-52-generic Sun May 21 10:53 - 22:41  (11:48)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 09:48 - down   (01:03)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 09:47 - 09:48  (00:01)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 09:45 - 09:47  (00:01)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 09:44 - 09:45  (00:00)
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-52-generic Sun May 21 09:44 - 10:52  (01:08)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 09:42 - down   (00:01)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 09:20 - 09:42  (00:21)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 08:27 - 09:20  (00:53)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 06:44 - 08:26  (01:42)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 06:43 - 06:44  (00:01)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 06:27 - 06:43  (00:15)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 06:25 - 06:27  (00:01)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 06:25 - 06:25  (00:00)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 06:24 - 06:24  (00:00)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 05:52 - 06:24  (00:31)
anita    tty7         :0               Sun May 21 05:43 - 05:52  (00:09)
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-52-generic Sun May 21 05:42 - 09:44  (04:01)
anita    tty7         :0               Sat May 20 18:18 - down   (00:00)
anita    tty7         :0               Sat May 20 11:59 - 18:17  (06:18)
anita    tty7         :0               Sat May 20 11:20 - 11:59  (00:38)
anita    tty7         :0               Sat May 20 10:57 - 11:20  (00:22)
anita    tty7         :0               Sat May 20 10:53 - 10:57  (00:04)
anita    tty7         :0               Sat May 20 10:48 - 10:53  (00:04)
anita    tty7         :0               Sat May 20 10:00 - 10:48  (00:48)
anita    tty7         :0               Sat May 20 09:57 - 09:59  (00:02)
anita    tty7         :0               Sat May 20 09:54 - 09:57  (00:03)
anita    tty7         :0               Sat May 20 05:45 - 09:53  (04:08)
anita    tty7         :0               Sat May 20 05:37 - 05:44  (00:07)
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-52-generic Sat May 20 05:36 - 18:18  (12:42)
**anita    tty7         :0               Fri May 19 22:39 - crash  (06:57)**
anita    tty7         :0               Fri May 19 22:30 - 22:39  (00:08)
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-52-generic Fri May 19 22:29 - 18:18  (19:48)
anita    tty7         :0               Fri May 19 19:34 - down   (02:55)
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-36-generic Fri May 19 19:34 - 22:29  (02:55)
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-36-generic Fri May 19 19:32 - 19:33  (00:00)

wtmp begins Fri May 19 19:32:30 2017
```